# Umbraco 7 Forms doesn't save RadioButtonList field value when using Save as umbraco document

Tags: forms, umbraco, radiobuttonlist, umbraco-contour

My site is running Umbraco 7.4.1, using Forms 4.2.1.

I'm saving the content of a form as Umbraco document, using the correct workflow for that. Everything works fine, except the data in my RadioButtonList doesn't transfer when I save.

I've tried setting the values by hand or using the same Data Type as a Prevalue source, to no effect. Is there something specific to do in the case of Radio Button List when using the Save as doc option that isn't apparent up first?

Comment: Does it save correctly if you try saving as a normal form emtry? Try asking over on our.umbraco.org - or, as this sounds a bit like a bug, report it on issues.umbraco.org :-/

Comment: Yes, the value is saved correctly in the Form entries. I've posted on their Forum too, but knowing that questions get answered a lot faster here, I tried both places.

I'm hesitant to post it as a bug already, as I'm not that familiar with the new implementation of Forms vs Contour.